# JavaScript in CSS lost on postback (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I am using the library 'CSS3 Pie' to allow me to use border-radius with previous IE a treat, by having the CSS style for the element like this:

```
border: 1px solid #122541;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
behaviour: url('../Content/Scripts/PIE.htc');
```

It works a treat, however when the page is postback (I am using an UpdatePanel if that makes any difference), the JS in PIE.htc that allows border-radius to work, doesn't fire so in previous IE versions the corners go back to being square.

What can I put in my Page_Load to essentially 'refire' the CSS on postback? Or is there another fix?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the JS edition of PIE (link: http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/) and call a script on postback with something like this:

```
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myScriptName", "<script>if (window.PIE) {$('.rounded').each(function() {PIE.attach(this);});}</script>");
```